# How to find efficiently sequence of values in R and work on them

Tags: r, while-loop, sequence

Let's say I've an array of integers, for example:

```
p<-c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
```

I need an efficient way to find all the sequences of maximum two "0". I did:

```
j<-2
while (j<length(p)) {
    if(p[j-1]==1&&p[j]==0&&p[j+1]==1){ 
        #do stuff
        j<-j+2
    } else if (p[j-1]==1&&p[j]==0&&p[j+1]==0&&p[j+2]==1){
        #do stuff
        j<-j+3
    } else {
        j<-j+1
    }
}
```

which works properly but, since I'm working with a huge vector in the real case I wonder if there is any smarter way to do it.

Comment: See also `rle`.

Comment: what are you expecting returned? in your example there are no examples of 'sequences of maximum two "0" '.

Comment: @SymbolixAU - one 0 is less than two 0's, isn't it? But I agree generally that it is not a clearly specified question.

Comment: @thelatemail well, yes, but is it a sequence?

Comment: @SymbolixAU - hmm.. point taken. But what is the sound of one hand clapping?

Comment: @thelatemail - are you standing near a wooded area? Also, does the sequence of three `0`s count as two individual sequences of two `0`s?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with these values, so I don't know if you want to count them, identify where they are, or change them. Hopefully this gets you started.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

p <- c(0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0)
```

Define a tidy structure with the run-length-encoded data and the string representation of those runs

```
p_rle <- bind_cols(rle(p)) %>% 
  mutate(str = strrep(values, lengths))

p_rle
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   lengths values   str
#>     <int>  <dbl> <chr>
#> 1       1      0     0
#> 2       1      1     1
#> 3       3      0   000
#> 4       2      1    11
#> 5       1      0     0
#> 6       1      1     1
#> 7       1      0     0
```

If needed, these can be split back out

```
p_rle$str
#> [1] "0"   "1"   "000" "11"  "0"   "1"   "0"
```

To explicitly select only runs of `0` with `2` or less

```
filter(p_rle, values == 0, lengths <= 2)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   lengths values   str
#>     <int>  <dbl> <chr>
#> 1       1      0     0
#> 2       1      0     0
#> 3       1      0     0
```

If you wanted to know *where* they appeared, you'll need to do something else.